# How to sort Y-axis labels different for each row in my plot?

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I want each subplot to sort the labels based on the value defining the size of the bar.

See example image:

[image]

```
data = {'label': ['A','A','B','B'], 'variable': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'], 'value':[2,4,3,1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
    selector = alt.selection_single(empty='all', fields=['label'])
    bar = alt.Chart(df,title='My Plot').mark_bar().encode(
        alt.Y('label', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="mean", order='ascending'), axis=alt.Axis(title='Label')),
        alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%', title='Value')),
        alt.Row('variable', title='Variable'),
        color=alt.condition(selector, alt.value('orange'), alt.value('lightgray')),
        tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('label', title='Label'),
                 alt.Tooltip('value:Q', format='.2%', title='Value'),]
    ).add_selection(selector)
    chart = (bar).properties(width=700, height=300)
    display(chart)
```

In the example, the labels (A, B) are now sorted based on the mean of all values for those labels. I want the order to be B-A for label X and A-B for label Y (so descending based on the value of the label showed in the row of the Altair plot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design facet charts share their axes, so it means that when you sort the column you are sorting *both* axes by the *entire* dataset.

If you  would like each chart to have its axis sorted individually, I believe the only way to do that is to manually filter the dataset and concatenate the charts. Here is one way you might do this:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A','A','B','B'],
                   'variable': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'value':[2,4,3,1]})

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
  alt.Y('label', axis=alt.Axis(title='Label'), 
        sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="sum", order='descending')),
  alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='d', title='Value')),
  tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('label', title='Label'),
           alt.Tooltip('value:Q', format='d', title='Value'),],
)

alt.vconcat(
  base.transform_filter("datum.variable == 'x'").properties(title='x'),
  base.transform_filter("datum.variable == 'y'").properties(title='y'),
  title='My Chart'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jake, we can actually use `resolve` to make facet use independent scale. (See my answer.) :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried using facet but that did not resolve the issue. I provide the code here because it can maybe inspire a solution :

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A','A','B','B'],
               'variable': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
               'value':[2,4,3,1]})
bar = alt.Chart(df,title='My Plot').mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('label', axis=alt.Axis(title='Label'), 
          sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="values", order='descending')),
    alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='d', title='Value')),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('label', title='Label'),
             alt.Tooltip('value:Q', format='d', title='Value'),]
).facet(
    row='variable:O'
)
bar
```

[image: sort grouped bar chart]

Still the row order is ['B', 'A'] for variable x and y. I was hoping to have ['A', 'B] for the variable y bar chart.

Further elaborating on the solution provided by jakevdp, i obtain this:

```
selector = alt.selection_single(empty='all', fields=['label'])
base = alt.Chart(df, title='My Plot').mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('label', axis=alt.Axis(title='Label'), sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="sum", order='descending')),
    alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='d', title='Value')),
    color=alt.condition(selector, alt.value('orange'), alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('label', title='Label'),
             alt.Tooltip('value:Q', format='d', title='Value'),]
).add_selection(selector)

bar = alt.vconcat(title='My Chart')
for v in df['variable'].unique():
    bar &= base.transform_filter(f"datum.variable == '{v}'").properties(title=f"'{v}'")

bar
```

[image: grouped bar chart with selector and ordering per chart]

Answer (score 2):

Facet has shared scales by default, but you can override scale resolution with the resolve property:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A','A','B','B'],
                   'variable': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'value':[2,4,3,1]})

alt.Chart(df,title='My Plot').mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('label', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="mean", order='descending'), axis=alt.Axis(title='Label')),
    alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%', title='Value'))
).facet(
    alt.Row('variable', title='Variable'),
    resolve={"scale": {"y": "independent"}}
)
```

[image]

Note that you can no longer use the row encoding shorthand in Altair 2 since unit specifications with row/column in Altair 2 (and Vega-Lite 2) do not have the `resolve` property.  We now added `resolve` to Vega-Lite 3, thus I think you should be able to do the following once Altair 3 is out:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': ['A','A','B','B'],
                   'variable': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'value':[2,4,3,1]})

alt.Chart(df,title='My Plot', resolve={"scale": {"y": "independent"}}).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.Y('label', sort=alt.EncodingSortField(field="value", op="mean", order='descending'), axis=alt.Axis(title='Label')),
    alt.X('value:Q', axis=alt.Axis(format='%', title='Value')),
    alt.Row('variable', title='Variable')
)
```